# Longest prefix of array equal to a value

Tags: python, numpy

I have NumPy arrays of strings that represent a segmentation of a sequence. `B` is the start of a segment of interest, `I` its continuation, `O` is outside any segment. E.g., in the following array, there are three segments of interest:

```
>>> y
array(['B', 'I', 'I', 'O', 'B', 'I', 'O', 'O', 'B', 'O'], 
      dtype='|S1')
```

I can find the segments starts easily with `np.where(y == "B")[0]`. But now I'm trying to also find the length of the segment, i.e. the length of the longest prefix that is equal to `I`. I can do so using `itertools.takewhile`:

```
>>> from itertools import takewhile
>>> lengths = [1 + sum(1 for _ in takewhile(lambda x: x == "I", y[start + 1:]))
...            for start in np.where(y == "B")[0]]
>>> lengths
[3, 2, 1]
```

which, to be honest, works fine, but is there a vectorized way to achieve this?

Comment: Out of curiosity is there a list of how all numpy methods scale somewhere?

Comment: @Ophion: not that I know of. Most are just linear time, but searching and sorting obviously can't be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A segment starts with a `'B'`:

```
starts = np.where(y == 'B')[0]
```

A segment ends where a `'B'` or `'I'` is followed by something other than an `'I'`, or by the end of the sequence:

```
ends = np.where(((y == 'B') | (y == 'I')) & np.r_[y[1:] != 'I', len(y)])[0]
```

This gives the segment lengths:

```
(ends - starts) + 1
array([3, 2, 1])
```

---

Edit: here's a simpler approach: insert a fictive `B` at the end, then take the difference in the positions of the (real or fictive) `B`s, excluding `O`s:

```
np.diff(np.where(np.r_[y[y != 'O'], ['B']] == 'B')[0])
array([3, 2, 1])
```

Answer (score 1):

Search sorted can help here:

```
>>> y
array(['B', 'I', 'I', 'O', 'B', 'I', 'O', 'O', 'B', 'O'],
      dtype='|S1')
>>> start=np.where(y=='B')[0]
>>> end=np.where(y=='O')[0]

>>> end[np.searchsorted(end,start)]-start
array([3, 2, 1])
```

Another approach:

```
>>> mask=np.concatenate(([True],(np.diff(end)!=1)))
>>> mask
array([ True,  True, False,  True], dtype=bool)
>>> end[mask]-start
array([3, 2, 1])
```